# RSA SecurID integration with OpenAM getting "User csr's access is denied."

Tags: ldap, openam, securid

I want to integrate RSA securid with openAM as the second step in openam chain. I am using openam version 14.0 and

1. First I have created a secure using RSA authentication manager and downloaded the config file and set the sdconf.rec file path in openam.
2. I have added the RSA securid plugin properly into openam and in the
   openam section, I have to create the RSA module after the LDAP module.
3. Then download the securid token file and set it with RSA
   authentication token generate tool and generate a passcode.
4. When login to the openam it is asking for LDAP username and password as
   first, step and it is redirecting to userid and passcode page as
   second step but issue is after entering the userid and generated
   passcode by the tool it is not working and in the below log
   file in the path showing below mentioned error and **csr** is the user id .

**[2020-12-16 14:50:54,003] WARN http-nio-8080-exec-7 - User csr's access is denied.**

Please check on this not sure all the steps are done properly if there any guide or documentation to integrate this correct way share me.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow? Is there any source code to see or this this a problem of an existing software? In case of the first, please include a minimum workable example. In the latter case, this question does not belong to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks rugk, for responding and this basically setting up with RSA authentication manager and openAM interface level and configurations, no code involvement.

Comment: Which OpenAM fork is being used? It's quite confusing that multiple projects took over ForgeRock's name but there is no ForgeRock OpenAM 14.0.